# How to merge a column from multiple rows into a single string

Tags: mysql, concatenation, coalesce

I have a table which has 2 rows[image: check image] now I would like to merge these rows and get a single string. something like this 'santhosh,santhosh'

I checked some examples suggesting to use COALESCE tried like this

```
set @col = '';
SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + ',', '') + name into @col
  FROM cricketers limit 20;
select @col;
```

but I never got the expected results, how should I achieve this, I'm running this inside a procedure. i would like to use the variable @col for doing a query like this

```
select * from table where id in (@col)
```

if I'm not following the correct process please suggest something.

Comment: select * from table where id in (@col) won't work id will be compared to 'santhosh,santhosh' in it;s entirety not to each element in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Coalesce simply allows to replace NULL with another value. It cannot solve your task.
2. `+` does not concatenate strings, it is arithmetic addition operator only.
3. If you need to concatenate values from a lot of rows into single value then you should use `GROUP BY` (maybe implicit) and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] name [ORDER BY name])
FROM cricketers;
```

If you do not need to remove duplicates then remove `DISTINCT`.

If you need to limit the amount of values concatenated then you may concatenate then remove excess values by:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] name [ORDER BY name]), ',', 20)
FROM cricketers;
```

or select needed rows amount in subquery:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name [ORDER BY name])
FROM ( SELECT [DISTINCT] name
       FROM cricketers
       [ORDER BY name]
       LIMIT 20 ) subquery;
```

`ORDER BY` expression presence is strongly recommended - without them you will receive indefinite values ordering (and in the case of amount limitation - their selection).

Comment: if we want to limit the number of cricketers added each time is it possible?

Comment: @santhosh If you need to obtain a lot of concatenated values where each value matches some time range then you must use explicit GROUP BY with according expression. In this case only the solution with the subquery is applicable.